# ATI Radeon Kaveri - cannot change screen resolution, 640x480 when using dual screen

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, xfce, radeon, amd-graphics

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with XFCE, with ATI Radeon Kaveri graphics (integrated on the motherboard).

I have 1 screen connected on the VGA port, and trying to add 1 TV on the HDMI port.

I cannot change the resolution using XFCE display settings, or with the xrandr command line tool.

If I plug only the VGA screen, it is used with its native resolution : 1920x1080.

If I plug the VGA screen and the HDMI TV, the display is mirrored on both screens at 640x480 resolution.

In both cases, the Xorg log shows that Xorg loads the Radeon driver, but the fbdev driver claims the video card, then the Radeon driver is unloaded. I guess there is a problem there ?

## Info with VGA screen only

### inxi -F

```
System:    Host: faivre-desktop Kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: Gigabyte product: N/A serial: N/A
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: F2A78M-HD2 v: x.x serial: N/A BIOS: American Megatrends v: FB date: 04/27/2015
CPU:       Quad core AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G (-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 1522 MHz 2: 1423 MHz 3: 1396 MHz 4: 1396 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: modesetting,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.5
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-32-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169
           IF: eth1 state: down mac: 40:8d:5c:0b:07:9a
           Card-2: Ralink RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter driver: rt73usb
           IF: wlan0 state: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (93.9% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_HD502HI size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD5000AAJS size: 500.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 125G used: 111G (94%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 1.88GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 34.4C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 200 Uptime: 3 min Memory: 527.2/6912.5MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

### xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

### lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  3
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
arc4                   16384  2
rt73usb                32768  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt73usb
rt2x00lib              53248  2 rt73usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              778240  2 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
kvm_amd                86016  0
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
cfg80211              622592  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_amd
crc_itu_t              16384  1 rt73usb
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
k10temp                16384  0
fam15h_power           16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
mac_hid                16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
pata_acpi              16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
chash                  16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  0
ttm                   106496  0
drm_kms_helper        172032  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_piix4              24576  0
pata_atiixp            16384  0
ahci                   36864  4
drm                   401408  2 ttm,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  86016  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
hid_cherry             16384  0
video                  45056  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_cherry
```

### Xorg.0.log

https://pastebin.com/pEwHKXXw

## Info with VGA screen and HDMI TV

### inxi -F

```
System:    Host: faivre-desktop Kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: Gigabyte product: N/A serial: N/A
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: F2A78M-HD2 v: x.x serial: N/A
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: FB date: 04/27/2015
CPU:       Quad core AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G (-MCP-) 
           cache: 8192 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 1742 MHz 2: 1446 MHz 3: 1397 MHz 4: 1396 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: modesetting,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 640x480@73.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.5
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-32-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169
           IF: eth1 state: down mac: 40:8d:5c:0b:07:9a
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (93.9% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_HD502HI size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD5000AAJS size: 500.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 125G used: 111G (94%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 1.88GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 25.4C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 199 Uptime: 1 min Memory: 478.9/6912.5MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

### xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

### lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
input_leds             16384  0
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
joydev                 24576  0
kvm_amd                86016  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_amd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
fam15h_power           16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
pata_acpi              16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
chash                  16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  0
ttm                   106496  0
drm_kms_helper        172032  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
hid_cherry             16384  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
pata_atiixp            16384  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  4
i2c_piix4              24576  0
drm                   401408  2 ttm,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
video                  45056  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_cherry
```

### Xorg.0.log

[https://pastebin.com/VXV57ft3](https://pastebin.com/pEwHKXXw)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found that this was due to an old setting :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`

I removed the `nomodeset` option, ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted, then the Radeon module was used and I could change each screen's resolution.